# Apache TrafficServer - no response from Jenkins in reverse-proxy configuration

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-traffic-server

I am trying ApacheTrafficServer (5.3.5) on my OpenBSD/PFSense routers (dedicated PC with 5 1Mbs ports). I mentioned here the OpenBSD/PFSense host but do not expect it to make a difference, but I may be wrong.

In remap.config I have the following entries:

```
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.referer_filter INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.referer_format_redirect INT 1

# jenkins 
map_with_referer http://jenkins/ http://jenkins-ci.shm:8001/
reverse_map http://jenkins-ci.shm:8001/ http://jenkins/
```

What I get when I enter "http://jenkins/" in the browser is a browser that goes out to neverland, and never returns.

How do I troubleshoot this?

*Update*
To preempt some questions: Yes Jenkins resolves to the pfsense/trafficserver box and yes jenkins-ci resolves to the machine running jenkins. Yes trafficserver listens on port 80 and port 443 on the LAN interfaces only, and both machines are in the lan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out this weekend.

There was an error in the remap.config file. The a log file in /var/log/trafficserver/diags.log showed it up. TrafficServer was not listening to any remap config entry beyond the error.

Answer (score 0):

The config above should not go into remap.config - half of it should be in records.config

in records.config:

```
CONFIG proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.referer_filter INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.http.referer_format_redirect INT 1
```

And in remap.config:

```
# jenkins 
map_with_referer http://jenkins/ http://jenkins-ci.shm:8001/
reverse_map http://jenkins-ci.shm:8001/ http://jenkins/
```

Mentioning that for completeness, although I guess it's a typo here rather than an actual misconfiguration.

The fact that it appears to be timing out suggests two things.  Either ATS is running fine, and it's having internal problems which should be captured in its logs (especially enabling debug logging), or the connection is never reaching ATS at all.  You might want to try a few cURL commands to confirm connectivity between the various elements.

- from the client `curl -i http://jenkins/`
- from the server where ATS is running: `curl -i --resolve "jenkins:80:<ext_ip or lo_ip>" http://jenkins/` and `curl -i http://jenkins-ci.shm:8001/`

Comment: You're very welcome!  Feel free to upvote or accept the answer